# query for Max/Min settings in multiple instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Hi I am trying to get the settings for Max and Min memory settings in all instances in sql server

This query below gives the info for the instance being used.

```
SELECT name, value, value_in_use, [description] 
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name like '%server memory%'
```

Here is sample output:

[image: Here is sample output]

Does anyone know how to get similar results but on multiple instances?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to execute query's on mutiple instances. PowerShell, SSIS or even a batch file. But if you just want to execute some ad hoc query's then the easiest way might be to create a group of registered servers.

Open the registered servers window

[image]

Register all your servers.

[image]

Open a new query on the group of servers.

[image]

Execute your SQL code in the new query window and it should return the results of all servers in the group.